# Laravel data table three-level relationship search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, datatable

I used Yajra/Laravel-Datatables to manage the records, and I added a searching feature for this table. I'm having trouble with the three-level relationship record search.

**tables**

- Lead table
- Agent table
- User table

```
$data = LeadInquiry::select(
    'lead_inquiries.*',
    'agent_leads.agent_id',
    'sender_detail.first_name as sender_first_name',
    'sender_detail.last_name as sender_last_name',
    'sender_detail.email as sender_email',
    'receiver_detail.first_name as
receiver_first_name',
    'receiver_detail.last_name as receiver_last_name',
    'receiver_detail.email as receiver_email'
)
    ->join('agent_leads', 'agent_leads.lead_id', 'lead_inquiries.map_id')
    ->join(
        'users as sender_detail',
        'lead_inquiries.sender_id',
        'sender_detail.id'
    )
    ->join(
        'users as receiver_detail',
        'lead_inquiries.receiver_id',
        'receiver_detail.id'
    )
    ->where('agent_leads.agent_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->latest();

filter(function ($query) use ($search) {
    if ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->Where('user', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->orwhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $query->orwhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $query->orwhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: laravel eloquent out of the box do not support 3 level deep relationship, however you can add these package staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep, read the documentation for more info how to use it

Comment: `I'm having trouble` is not a question. What have you tried? What didn't work? What error message did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing -

```
filter(function ($query) use ($search) {
    if ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->Where('user', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->orwhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $query->orwhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                $query->orwhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

with

```
if ($search) {
    $data->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('sender_detail.first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        $query->orwhere('sender_detail.last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        $query->orwhere('sender_detail.email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
}
```